# In a loop, is to create new object is so necessary?

Tags: c#

```
var users = new List<User>();
User user = new User();
foreach (var element in elements)
{                
    try
    {
        user.Id = element.Attribute("Id").Value;
        user.Reputation = element.Attribute("Reputation").Value;
        user.CreationDate = DateTime.Parse(element.Attribute("CreationDate").Value);
        user.DisplayName = element.Attribute("DisplayName").Value;
        user.LastAccessDate = Convert.ToDateTime(element.Attribute("LastAccessDate").Value);
        user.WebsiteUrl = element.Attribute("WebsiteUrl").Value;
        user.Location = element.Attribute("Location").Value;
        user.Age = Convert.ToInt32(element.Attribute("Age").Value);
        user.AboutMe = element.Attribute("AboutMe").Value;
        user.Views = element.Attribute("Views").Value.ToInt32();
        user.UpVotes = element.Attribute("UpVotes").Value.ToInt32();
        user.DownVotes = element.Attribute("DownVotes").Value.ToInt32();

        users.Add(user);
    }
    catch (NullReferenceException)
    {
        // do nothing
    } 
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}
```

The expression `User user = new User();` is used outside the foreach loop. My intention is to avoid instantiating new `User` object, if a loop runs 10000000 time (suppose), what if I just instantiate a single time and on each loop I just change its contents variable and adding to the a list. But what happen... I although get all different users, but in my final list there is only one user (the first user) and it has as many copies as loop runs...
The problem can be solved the taking the express `User user = new User();` in foreach loop, but I'm not convinced by myself, why it need to instantiate a new object on each loop ?..... Please clear me

Comment: Yes, put it inside the loop. Otherwise you're just modifying the one object every single time. If you want multiple users, you're going to need multiple objects, simple as that.

Comment: Yes, if you don't want to add the same user 10000000 times, then you want to allocate in the loop. You also want to get rid of the catch for `NullReferenceException` and for diagnostic purposes, you want to use `e.ToString()`.

Answer (score 4):

When you add it to the list, you adding a reference to the object you are creating and the list is keeping it for future use.

By putting the "new" inside the loop, you are adding a new object each time.  You get a performance hit because you are allocating memory for it.  There are ways to mitigate this so the hit is somewhere else (i.e. a pool/list of them created when your program starts up that you use when the program runs), but you **must** allocate them somewhere.

By **not** putting a "new" inside the loop, every element of the list points back to the same single object you created.

If you want to keep different information for each object, it must be stored somewhere.

**This concept is NOT just for C#**.

Answer (score 3):

Reference types and value types are different.This is because every time in the foreach loop you just changing one User and add it to your list.

`Value types:` *A data type is a value type if it holds the data within its own memory allocation.*

`Reference types:` *A reference type contains a pointer to another memory location that holds the data.*

Check this for more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs.aspx

As the others said you should move your `User` definition inside of your foreach loop:

```
    foreach (var element in elements)
    {
      User user = new User();
      ...
    }
```

Comment: Well, you are right, but I'm not convinced yet...How ..
Look .... user (reference type is a pointer to some memory locations ...... id (string), displayName(string), creationDate(datetime) ....so and so forth....... when every time on a loop the memomry contents are being changes at the same memory locations... and the user is just a pointer, it should ....ohhhhhhh yes ...yesss... I now convinced, so in list of IEnumberalbe there must be different user pointers and must be pointing to different users memory spaces...

Comment: Finally, Yes I need a new object on each iteration.. thanks of All